# Restructuring PHP array

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have tried many different variation, but cannot get the right structure. Maybe, you expert might what to give it a try.

What I need to do is return the therapist who may have multiple children assigned to him. It will return the children's schedules that are assigned to him.

I have tried the following Code. This is the closest I can get to the format I need.

```
    // Grab the therapist    
    $therapist = $this->Therapist->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Therapist.' . $this->Therapist->primaryKey => $id)));
    // Grab the child(ren) assigned to the therapist
   // Returns id as key and name as value.
    $children =  $this->Child->get_children($id);
    $schedule = array();
   // Loop through the assigned children and get the id (key).
   foreach($children as $key => $value):
        // Loop through and grab all the scheduled days and times for child(ren).
        foreach($this->Schedule->get_full_schedule($key) as $child):
            // Have the child name at the top of the array. 
            if($name != $child['Child']['child_name']):
                 $schedule[] = array_push($schedule,  array('child_name' => $child['Child']['child_name']));
                $name = $child['Child']['child_name'];
            endif;
                // Get all the scheduled days for the child and add to array.
                if($child['Schedule']['child_id'] == $child['Child']['id']):
                    $schedule[]['Schedule'] =  $child['Schedule'];
                endif;
        endforeach;
    endforeach;
```

Which outputs the following Array:

```
   Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                           [child_name]  => John Smith
                        )

                    [1] => 1
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [Schedule] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 19
                                    [child_id] => 197
                                    [days] => Monday
                                    [start_time] => 17:00:00
                                    [end_time] => 22:00:00
                                )

                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [child_name]  => Jane Smith
                        )

                    [4] => 4
                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [Schedule] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 16
                                    [child_id] => 138
                                    [days] => Monday
                                    [start_time] => 09:00:00
                                    [end_time] => 17:00:00
                                )

                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [Schedule] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 17
                                    [child_id] => 138
                                    [days] => Sunday
                                    [start_time] => 09:00:00
                                    [end_time] => 12:00:00
                                )

                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [Schedule] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 18
                                    [child_id] => 138
                                    [days] => Tuesday
                                    [start_time] => 09:00:00
                                    [end_time] => 17:00:00
                                )

                        )

                )
```

What I would like is:

```
                Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                           [child_name]  => John Smith
                           [0] => Array
                               (
                                [Schedule] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 19
                                        [child_id] => 197
                                        [days] => Monday
                                        [start_time] => 17:00:00
                                        [end_time] => 22:00:00
                                    )
                            )
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [child_name]  => Jane Smith
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [Schedule] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 16
                                            [child_id] => 138
                                            [days] => Monday
                                            [start_time] => 09:00:00
                                            [end_time] => 17:00:00
                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [Schedule] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 17
                                            [child_id] => 138
                                            [days] => Sunday
                                            [start_time] => 09:00:00
                                            [end_time] => 12:00:00
                                        )

                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [Schedule] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 18
                                            [child_id] => 138
                                            [days] => Tuesday
                                            [start_time] => 09:00:00
                                            [end_time] => 17:00:00
                                        )

                        )

                )
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thank,
Greg

Comment: Does it have to be EXACTLY like that, or is there a way you can generalize it like.... "I want an array where each child has an array of dates" ?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I just need it in a format, so I can pass it to a view and build out a table of the schedule for each child.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about just using [Containable Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html)?  Seems MUCH easier than the way you're trying to do it:

```
$this->Therapist->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Therapist.' . $this->Therapist->primaryKey => $id
    ),
    'contain' => array(
        'Child' => array(
            'Schedule'
        )
    )
));
```

Not only is it a lot easier, but your data should come back in an acceptable and nested format.

Comment: Yes, I tried to put something together using Containable. I was trying it in the Schedule Model, however I will give this a try. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: I tried it. Everything worked, but didn't return the schedule for each child. Sorry.

Comment: @GregFox - then there's something else wrong with your code.  Bottom line, this answer is "use containable behavior".  Beyond that, you might need to ask a question about why your associations are wrong, or why containable isn't working as it should for you.  My guess is you didn't set recursive to -1 per the instructions, but I can't be sure without seeing all your code.

Comment: Once I fixed my relationships, it worked like a charm. Thanks.